# Are there any good examples or case studies of Project Management SharePoint sites on Modern Experience?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modern-experience, project-management

I am looking to implement a PMO site in my tenant and one of the requirements I have is to be able to aggregate project status updates in a dashboard from multiple projects.

We are running in Modern Experience, so I am wondering if there are any examples or case studies if anyone has implemented project SharePoint sites on SharePoint Online?

Previously, I would have used Content Search web parts with stylings. I assume Highlighted Content webpart may serve me here, but I wanted to see if anyone else has done something similar.

Comment: Are you aware of Microsoft’s recently released “Project Roadmaps”? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Project-Blog/Announcing-Project-Roadmaps/ba-p/268466

Comment: Yup, I also had a look at that. But I didnt see how I can integrate that into SharePoint sites where we can store Project artifacts.